# Integrating factor $xy'=y^2x+y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$xy'=y^2x+y \implies (y^2x+y)dx-(x)dy=0$

$P=(y^2x+y), Q=-x$

The appropriate integrating factor for get this ode as an exact ode is $\mu=y^{-2}$.

$(\ln \mu)'= \dfrac {Q_x-P_y}P=\frac{-2xy-2}{y^2x+y}$ depends on $x$ , so how it's possible that the integrating factor is $y^{-2}$.

Were I am getting wrong ?

Comment: You are failing somehow to evaluate $Q_x-P_y$ correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$P=(y^2x+y), Q=-x$$

So

$$\dfrac{Q_x - P_y}{P} = \dfrac{-1 - (2 xy +1)}{x y^2 + y} = \dfrac{-2(1 + xy)}{~~~y(1+xy)} = -\dfrac{2}{y}$$

We can now integrate both sides wrt $y$ and take the exponential of both sides.

This results in

$$\mu(y) = e^{\int -2/y~dy} = \dfrac{1}{y^2}$$